# how can i change all urls of old website

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, .htaccess, 301-redirect, redirect-url

i just remove my website from hmsaver.com to homemarket.ae now every thing is working but i want to ask is that possible if any visitor came from google to hmsaver.com and he redirect with same url to https://www.hmsaver.com/electronics.html or any link of hmsaver.com to http://homemarket.ae/electronics.html

Answer (score 2):

add below in your old domian .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: After setting up the redirect rule here, You should also review your CMS pages & static blocks.  Some of the older WYSIWYG editors have been known to insert fully qualified domains in the links they generate either for embedded media assets or in anchor tags.